# How to optimaze looping , get data from Mysql Lumen

Tags: laravel, lumen

I join data between member data and followers data, I want to check if the followers data is there or not in the database, if it doesn't exist then it means they are not followers, but the code I created resulted in a long process. hen i access **getStatus2** function the process becomes slow

How to do it, so that the code that I create can process data quickly?

```
    public function ListFollowers($member_id)
{
    
        $get_data=DB::table('member_sso')
           ->leftJoin('klaklik_member_followers', 'member_sso.member_sso_id', '=', 'klaklik_member_followers.following_id')
        //    ->leftJoin('klaklik_member_profile', 'klaklik_member_followers.following_id', '=', 'klaklik_member_profile.member_id')
            ->select('first_name','last_name','following_id','cover','klaklik_member_followers.created_date as following_date')
            ->where('klaklik_member_followers.member_id',$member_id)
            ->get();
          
        if (count($get_data)>0) {
            foreach($get_data as $key=>$value){
             
                    // $peccah=json_decode($value->profile_data);
                    $array['MEMBER_ID']=$value->following_id;
                    $array['USERNAME']=$value->first_name." ".$value->last_name;
                    if (empty($value->cover)) {
                        $array['MEMBER_IMAGE']='https://www.klaklik.com/assets/images/profile.png';
                    } else {
                        $array['MEMBER_IMAGE']="https://cdn-prv-city.klaklik.com/".$value->cover;  
                       
                    }
                   
                    $array['FOLLOWING_DATE']=$value->following_date;
                    $status=$this->getStatus2($value->following_id,$member_id);
                    if (count($status)>0) {
                       $array['STATUS']='0';
                       $array['STATUS_DEC']='FOLLOWING YOU';
                    }else{
                        $array['STATUS']='1';
                        $array['STATUS_DEC']='NOT FOLLOW YOU';
                    }
                    $result[]=$array;
                }   
        $response=$result;
        $data["STATUS"]=200;
        $data["MESSAGE"]="FOLLOWING DATA";
        $data["DATA"]=$response;
        
        }else{
            $data["STATUS"]=404;
            $data["MESSAGE"]="YOU HAVE NO FOLLOWERS";
            $data["DATA"]=(object) array();
        }
    return json_encode($data);
}

   public function getStatus2($member_id,$following_id){
    $get_data=DB::table('klaklik_member_followers')
                ->where('klaklik_member_followers.member_id',$member_id)
                ->where('klaklik_member_followers.following_id',$following_id)
                ->first();
    return $get_data;
}
```

Comment: Why not use [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent) instead?

Comment: I use Eloquent it remains the same, the process takes a long time @rkg

Comment: You don't have to loop if you use Eloquent.

Comment: can you give me example ? @rkg

Answer (score 0):

u may change  getStatus2 function to in_array()

get all the member's following_ids , then check the $value->following_id is in the following_ids.

Comment: can you give me example? @bjfuzzj

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop to query all of that. Utilize Laravel `Eloquent`. You just have to set the right relationship like so:

```
public function childrenRelationships()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Children', 'child_parent', 'child_id');
}

public function allChildrenRelationships()
{
    return $this->childrenRelationships()->with('allChildrenRelationships');
}
```

Then just call the relationship on your `Controller` like so:

```
public function getData($id)
{
    $model = Model::find($id)->with('allChildrenRelationships');
}
```